# How can I let Thunar call Catfish with its own date and time formatting settings?

Tags: xfce, thunar, thunar-custom-actions

This question arose when using Xubuntu 20.04 which uses Thunar version 1.18.14 in connection with Catfish version 1.4.13.

Thunar uses Catfish as search tool. I have set Thunar to use the ISO 8601 date and time format. However when I use Catfish through Thunar, it comes up with local date formatting.

I can however call Catfish from a terminal and give it the option `--iso-time`. Then it delivers its results in the same way as Thunar does when set to ISO 8601 date formatting. I have set Tunar's date formatting to

`"misc-date-style" type="string" value="THUNAR_DATE_STYLE_YYYYMMDD"`

(they are stored in the file `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/thunar.xml`).

**How can I let Thunar invoke Catfish with the option --iso-time** (or even more consistent: with the date formatting option set in its own initialization file) **?**